# img height attribute in @media specifity

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the following CSS, but although the image displays @60px on desktop resolution, it doesn't resize to 40px under the @media import. Is this something I am missing to do with specificity?:

```
@media (max-width: 976px) {
  #navigation .user .dropdown >a img {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height:40px;
 };
}

#navigation .user .dropdown>a img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    height:60px;
}
```

Comment: Order does matter.  That's why they are called cascading style sheets.  The last relevant definition wins.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the order of the code for it to work:

```
#navigation .user .dropdown>a img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    height:60px;
}

@media (max-width: 976px) {
     #navigation .user .dropdown >a img {
         margin-left: 10px;
         height:40px;
     };
}
```

Since you didn't wrap the "regular" code with `@media` query, it is executed in both cases. and for lower width display you basically had `height:40px;` followed by `height:60px;` - and it got overridden.

Answer (score 0):

`#navigation .user .dropdown >a img {` is not the same as `#navigation .user .dropdown>a img {`. A space in your CSS could be a problem in some Browsers, as it indicates all descendants.
See your `.dropdown >a`. Also switch the order of your code, so it looks like:

```
#navigation .user .dropdown>a img {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height:60px;
}
@media (max-width: 976px) {
  #navigation .user .dropdown>a img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    height:40px;
  }
}
```